# Dúvida - Relacionamento N para N

Tags: sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Estou desenvolvendo um modelo conceitual para gerenciamento de projetos.

Um **Projeto** pode ter várias fases.
Uma **Fase** pode estar pode estar em vários projetos.

As relações acima vai gerar uma outra tabela "**ProjetoFase**"
.
A minha dúvida é: 
Eu poderia usar a relação **ProjetoFase** como fase corrente do projeto? Se não, como eu poderia modelar o conceitual para identificar a fase corrente de um projeto?

[image: Qual seria a melhor opção para conseguir identificar uma fase corrente do projeto?]

Obrigado pela atenção! :D

Comment: Que campos teria a sua fase corrente de um projeto e como a indicava?

Comment: além das chaves estrangeiras, um campo **status**

Comment: Então e a tabela Fase não tem status?

Comment: Isso mesmo, não tem.

Comment: Não pode criar uma outra tabela chamada FaseCorrente? sendo que esta estaria ligada a um Projeto e uma Fase.
Que valores estaria a considerar modelar na coluna de Status?

Comment: O status não indicaria qual é a fase corrente do projeto? Isto é qual das instâncias do relacionamento Fase-Projeto indica a fase corrente?

Comment: @MauroAlmeida, a tabela FaseCorrente é já está sendo gerada com a relação N:M entre as tabelas Projeto e Fase. Na coluna status, na tabela FaseCorrente, eu estou considerando os valores: On time, Out of time, Risco, Encerrado.

Comment: Porquê usar palavras em inglês para uns estados do status e português para outros?

Comment: Eu adicionei a imagem com os modelos conceituais.
Qual das opções seria a correta para consultar uma fase corrente de um projeto?

Comment: Se, como você afirma, "Uma Fase pode estar pode estar em vários projetos" a sua opção 1 não faz sentido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O melhor modelo seria a opção 2, pois seria uma relação N para N, e nesse caso seria necessário criar uma terceira tabela para guardar os valores desse relacionamento, e nessa tabela você teria o campo status, contendo o status dessa relação.

Você pode usar chave composta nessa tabela FaseProjeto, que seria a união dos dois campos(idProjeto, idFase).

Segue abaixo uma imagem de como ficaria o modelo relacional

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]